# Slow samba write speed to ceph backend

Tags: samba, ceph

I have backend on cephfs cluster, mounted on gateway. Mount path is shared with samba 4.7.4. But my speed is low, about 1,5MB/s with small files (1k - 100k). I copy ot with win server 2008 client.
Locally i copy the same files 5-6 times faster. So i tried to use 5-6 clients to copy this files and got the same speed as locally.

I tried different socket options, but not get required speed

```
aio read size = 1
aio write size = 1
```

P.S. tried vfs_ceph, but did not get any profits. And with acl_xattr it working 4 times worse than mounted cephfs.

Comment: What is the performance writing to a samba share on a remote host backed by a 'simple' disk rather than ceph? Local disk write speeds aren't really comparable to network writes.

Comment: Approx the same. I find out, that its promlem with samba/windows, because i mounted the share on linux server with cifs and speed was the same, as local server, where samba server is running.